# Turning a fact table into a schema in sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a schema that collects a group of other schema but also include a Sum. This is what I have so far:

Create DDL -

```
CREATE TABLE ticket_sales 
  ( 
     theatreid     NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT fk1 REFERENCES theatre, 
     trowid        NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT fk2 REFERENCES theatre_row, 
     seasonid      NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT fk3 REFERENCES season, 
     productionid  NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT fk4 REFERENCES production, 
     clientid      NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT fk5 REFERENCES client, 
     ticketrevenue NUMBER(7) NOT NULL, 
     CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY (theatreid, trowid, seasonid, productionid, 
     clientid) 
  );
```

Insert DML -

```
INSERT INTO ticket_sales 
SELECT theatreid, 
       trowid, 
       seasonid, 
       productionid, 
       clientid, 
       ticketrevenue 
FROM   ( 
                SELECT   theatre.theatreid, 
                         theatre_row.trowid, 
                         season.seasonid, 
                         production.productionid, 
                         client.clientid, 
                         SUM(totalamount) ticketrevenue 
                FROM     notmydatabase.ticketpurchase 
                WHERE    extract(month FROM notmydatabase.preformance.pdate)=season.month 
                AND      to_number(to_char(notmydatabase.performance.pdate, 'WW'))=season.week
                AND      extract(day FROM notmydatabase.performance.pdate)=season.day 
                GROUP BY theatre.theatreid, 
                         theatre_row.trowid, 
                         season.seasonid, 
                         production.productionid, 
                         client.clientid);
```

when I run the insert part, it just comes up with table or view does not exist. I have no idea why. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *table or view does not exist* Which table? Post the entire error stack. It is important to debug as it contains lot of details.

Comment: Check by doing a simple select on everything your selecting from where the problem exactly is. My quess: You're not granted to select on the `notmydatabase`Object. Could be fixed with executing `grant select on [OBJECT] to [SHEMA_YOUR_EXECUTING_FROM]` connected to "notmydatabase".

Comment: the only error it shows me is ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: You're sure it's coming from the insert, not the create? Or both - if the create fails, the insert will get that error too. Do the tables you're referencing in the create (`theatre`, etc.) exist in your schema already, or in the teacher's schema? The insert has other problems, like not having `theatre` etc. in the inner `from` clause, and `preformance` instead of `performance`; but I don't think you're getting that far.

Comment: This is one of the tables I created and works and is referenced above.
'CREATE TABLE Theatre(
TheatreID number(2)  PRIMARY KEY, 
TheatreName VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,
Street VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
Town VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
County VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
MainTel VARCHAR2(15));'

Comment: Also a 'schema' is the owner of the tables; I'm not quite sure what term you're confusing it with here, possibly just 'table'. If this works you get a one-off snapshot of the total revenue when you run the insert; maybe you want a view instead, so you can always see the current total at the point you query it?

Comment: Ah ok, yes I'm just getting schema confused. Sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: If all your local tables exist, maybe the immediate issue is `notmydatabase.ticketpuchase` - should that have an `r` in it, as `notmydatabase.ticketpurchase`? It's still not a valid statement as you need all the other tables in the from with join clauses, but that might move you forward. I'd also suggest you use a client like SQL*Plus or SQL Developer that shows you more details about the errors you get, particularly the line number. Where are you running this now?

Answer (score 1):

The following might be the error cause -

1. `FROM     not mydatabase.ticketpuchase`

It is syntactically incorrect. I would rather expect `ORA-00903: invalid table name` error.

**More errors**

2. `ticketpuchase` should be `ticketpurchase`.
3. `preformance.pdate` should be `performance.pdate`.
4. The following tables are missing in the `FROM` clause

-

```
theatre 
theatre_row
season
production
client
```

Comment: Sorry, my typing error there notmydatabase is to cover for the real name of the database (I don't know if my teacher would appreciate me linking his name in it)

Comment: Can you execute it in `SQL*Plus` and copy paste your session in your question.

Comment: I don't believe the oracle I'm using has sql*plus (I can't find it)

Comment: If you have installed client then you would have it. Do you have any interactive tool like 'SQL Developer` or `TOAD` etc.? Execute it in command window or as a script to see the entire error stack.

Comment: @LalitKumarB - I suspect there should be an 'r' in 'purchase' too, which might be more relevant...

Comment: @AlexPoole, I too think so. `not mydatabase` should yield `ORA-00903`. There is something else wrong with the query. Anyway, I have asked OP to use any client tool and copy paste the entire error stack.

Comment: Yes there should be an 'r' in purchase. I feel like a bit of an idiot. It's still not working right but at least it's stop saying invalid table name. The new error is ORA-00904: "CLIENT"."CLIENTID": invalid identifier. I fixed one like this yesterday but I can't remember how

Comment: @LisaDuffin, you have another issue - `preformance.pdate`. It should be `performance.pdate`

Comment: @LisaDuffin, you need to join all the other tables like `client`, theatre`, `season` etc.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks. I removed client. so it was just clientid and it still has an issue with it

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem is that you're missing an `r` in the only table name you have in your `from` clause: `notmydatabase.ticketpuchase` should be `notmydatabase.ticketpurchase`. CHanging that will get rid of the ORA-00942.

But that will then reveal problems with the rest of the statement. You're referring to various other tables, such as with `client.clientid`, when those tables are not part of the query - the `client` table has not been specified in the `from` clause at all. You need to include all the tables you're referring to, and the join conditions. You seem to have misspelled `performance` as `preformance` in one place too.

I'm guessing a lot about the table structures and join conditions based on the keys you've defined but something like this may give you the general idea and something to work from:

```
INSERT INTO ticket_sales 
SELECT   theatre.theatreid, 
         theatre_row.trowid, 
         season.seasonid, 
         production.productionid, 
         client.clientid, 
         SUM(totalamount) ticketrevenue 
FROM     notmydatabase.ticketpurchase
JOIN     notmydatabase.performance
ON       notmydatabase.performance.performanceid = notmydatabase.ticketpurchase.performanceid
JOIN     theatre_row
ON       theatre_row.trowid = notmydatabase.ticketpurchase.trowid
JOIN     theatre
ON       theatre.theatreid = theatre_row.trowid
JOIN     production
ON       production.productionid = notmydatabase.performance.productionid
JOIN     client
ON       client.clientid = ticketpurchase.clientid
JOIN     season
ON       season.month = extract(month FROM notmydatabase.performance.pdate) 
AND      season.week = to_number(to_char(notmydatabase.performance.pdate, 'WW'))
AND      season.day = extract(day FROM notmydatabase.performance.pdate) 
GROUP BY theatre.theatreid, 
         theatre_row.trowid, 
         season.seasonid, 
         production.productionid, 
         client.clientid;
```

You don't need the extra level of subquery either. And you might want to look into table aliases, which will make the joins and other references shorter and easier to follow. And you might want consider using a view for something that calculates a sum, so you can always see the current value rather than a snapshot. I realise this is an exercise and a table with insert might be a requirement here though.

Mostly, though, you need to use a client that will show you where errors are occurring so you can start to figure out the issues, particularly typos and basic syntax mistakes.